# Convert Number to Float in Python

Tags: python, casting

Say I have a variable `x`. It currently holds the value 4 (`x = 4`). How would I change the value of `x` to a floating point number (such as `4.4`, or `4.0`)? The only thing I can think of is a reassignment, but I feel like this just isn't the right way to do it.

```
x = x + 0.0
```

Is there any way to do this with something like a standard library function or without reassignment?

Comment: You don't need to do it, Python will automagically change the data type of a variable based on what you do with it. For example, if x = 4, then you divide it by 3 by doing: x = x / 3 or (x /= 3), you will turn x into a float

Comment: @Ol'Reliable Unfortunately, division is probably the worst example to choose here, because in python2 your example would have returned 1 because it would assume integer division since both numbers are integers.  Perhaps the OP is using python2 and wants to turn the numbers into floats for this exact reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast it to float using the pythong in-built function [`float()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float):

```
In [154]: x = 4
In [155]: float(x)
Out[155]: 4.0
```

`x = float(x)` is all you need.

Comment: You really want `x = float(x)`, but it's the same idea.